# Modifying an element in a dataframe with iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change an element in a large dataframe

e.g

```
Keyword                         |cat1|cat2|cat3|
--------------------------------|----|----|----|
beach holiday                   |    |    |    |
package beach holiday           |    |    |    |
inclusive package beach holiday |    |    |    |
```

I run a method find_keywords(Keyword) which passes in the Key word e.g. "inclusive package beach holiday" which compares against a text list of categories and returns the first three relevant categories.

```
''' 
Input a Keyword, breaks it down and finds which category it matches
'''
def find_keywords(keywords):
words = keywords.split()
wordlist = []
for word in words:      
    if word in categories:
        wordlist.append(word)       
wordlist = wordlist [:3]    
return wordlist
```

In this case:

```
['inclusive','package','beach']
```

this is all fine and when i run my main method on the data

```
if __name__ == '__main__':


df = get_csv(csv)


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['Keyword'].lower()
    print(row['Keyword'])
    tokens = find_keywords(row['Keyword'])
    print(tokens)
```

it returns:

```
beach holiday
['beach','holiday']                   
package beach holiday  
['package','beach','holiday']         
inclusive package beach holiday 
['inclusive','package','beach']
```

How would i take the list for each and add it to the cat1/cat2/cat3 column

producing the dataframe:

```
Keyword                         |cat1   |cat2    |cat3   |
--------------------------------|----   |----    |----   |
beach holiday                   |beach  |holiday |       |
package beach holiday           |package|beach   |holiday|
inclusive package beach holiday |inclusive|package|beach |
```

Using @DaFanat's solution I was able to get what i asked for however I have a slight permutation on this, would it be possible check against a dictionary instead of a list?

e.g

```
{'beach': ['beach', 'sand', 'coast'],
'hotel': ['hotel', 'resort']}
```

and then apply the head term to the category, e.g if it found sand it would mark it beach.

My attempt:
    if **name** == '**main**':

```
df = get_csv(csv)
h = open('head_categories.txt','r')
mydict = h.read()
mydict = ast.literal_eval(mydict)




for key in mydict.keys():
    item = key
    if item in mydict[key]:
        target_cats = item
        find_keywords = lambda kw: [s for s in kw.split() if s in target_cats]

        df.loc[:, 'cat_list'] = df['Keyword'].apply(lambda x: find_keywords(x))
        for i in range(1, 4):
            df.loc[:, 'cat{0}'.format(i)] = df['cat_list'].apply(lambda x: x[i-1] if len(x) >= i else '')


print(df)
df.to_csv('kuoniTesting.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can do the job:

```
target_cats = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Keyword': ['cat dog cow', 'cat dog', 'dog sheep']})
find_keywords = lambda kw: [s for s in kw.split() if s in target_cats]

df.loc[:, 'cat_list'] = df['Keyword'].apply(lambda x: find_keywords(x))
for i in range(1, 4):
    df.loc[:, 'cat{0}'.format(i)] = df['cat_list'].apply(lambda x: x[i-1] if len(x) >= i else '')

     Keyword      cat_list         cat1 cat2 cat3
  0  cat dog cow  [cat, dog, cow]  cat  dog  cow
  1      cat dog       [cat, dog]  cat  dog     
  2    dog sheep            [dog]  dog
```

Comment: If I were to reference a dictionary rather than a list would this still work?

Comment: With little changes in the find_keywords function and in the lambda function within the apply, yes.

Comment: Ive tried to add a for loop around the outside to reference the keys of the dictionaries then checking the terms for the key against the tokens in the keyword. Is this the right direction to be going in?

Comment: Sorry, I lost track of the question. Please consider asking a new question or re edit your original question. + think of accepting my answer.